# Which callback must I use to get previous value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On update, I'm trying to send an email if previous value =! published and the new value is published. I tried after_save, before_action...

if for example

@ad.status == "pending" and updated to 'published'

@ad.status_was != 'published' return true

```
  class Shop::AdsController < Admin2Controller
    before_action :set_ad, only: %i[edit update destroy]
    before_action :send_notification_if_published, only: :update

    def send_notification_if_published
      return unless @ad.status_was != 'published' && @ad.status_published?
      notification = Notification.find_by(action: 'ad_published')

      subscribed_users = User.joins(:notification_preferences)
                             .where(notification_preferences: { notification_id: notification.id })

      subscribed_users.each do |user|
        NotificationsMailer.new(user, notification, self).deliver_later
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are you experiencing an issue? You haven't mentioned any problems and nothing appears to be amiss with what you posted.

Comment: @engineersmnky I added more informations ;)

Comment: I am still very unclear. Your code seems to do exactly what you are requesting so what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *before_action* `@ad` is what you get from `set_ad`. It hasn't been updated yet, and new `ad_params` are not yet assigned. So `@ad.status` and `@ad.status_was` are both `pending`.

```rb
# this is what you're doing
@ad = Ad.first
@ad.status     #=> "pending"
@ad.status_was #=> "pending"

# but you expect this, which doesn't happen
@ad.attributes = {status: "published"}
@ad.status     #=> "published"
@ad.status_was #=> "pending"

# this happens only after the update
@ad.update({status: "published"})
@ad.status                #=> "published"
@ad.status_was            #=> "published"
@ad.status_previously_was #=> "pending"
```

In a controller you can use `after_action`, or just put it in `update` action because you need to know that the ad was actually updated successfully.

In a model `after_update` should do it.

Use `status_was` after changing attributes. Use `status_previously_was` after saving those changes.

Comment: def update
    puts "was before #{@step.poi_end_id_was}" return 610
    if @step.update(step_params)
      puts "was after #{@step.poi_end_id_was}" return 584
      puts "changed? #{@step.poi_end_id_changed?}" return false
      puts "previously_changed? #{@step.poi_end_id_previously_changed?}" return false


Why previously_changed? #{@step.poi_end_id_previously_changed?}" return false in this case ?

Comment: @Ben not sure, `_id_previously_changed?` seem to work ok for me. you might want to post a separate question, because it's hard to decipher it from your comment.